# rotating image on html canvas has jagged edges on mobile browsers (bad anti aliasing)

Tags: html, canvas, rotation, mobile-website, antialiasing

As demonstrated in the following jsfiddle, I'm adding an image to a `canvas` element, and then rotating it around it's center:

http://jsfiddle.net/M7Z5u/6/

On mobile phones (ios, android) the image has jagged edges when rotating (to see the jagged edges in jsfiddle on an iphone you may have to zoom in on the image). This doesn't happen on desktop browsers.

Is there any way to smoothen the edges on mobile devices?

Comment: `is it working smoothly for other images??`

Comment: no, it works the same for all images

Comment: i'd bet it has to do with hiDPI (retina) this article is nice : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/  in short : to draw in hiDpi, have at hand a twice sized picture that you draw scaled by 0.5. Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/M7Z5u/7/ (half size, but hopefully no jaggies)

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511028/screen-resolution-on-a-phonegap-app/20511150#20511150

Comment: @GameAlchemist I think you're right. Viewing OP's fiddle (and your fiddle) produces jaggies on a MBP w/ retina.