# PhoneGap resolution same but results differ

Tags: android, ios, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I think my issue is similar to that referenced here:
[Screen Resolution On A PhoneGap App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511028/screen-resolution-on-a-phonegap-app)

Basiaclly I have an ipad and an android tablet, both with resolution of 1024 across, yet my screen displays correctly on the ipad, yet on the android, some of my output is wrapped.

The solution recommended in the above post is to insert the following 'viewport' within the document head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

I had this in originally, and the layout was the same but the fonts on the android were (almost) unreadable (9px ?) but were fine/readable on the ipad.

Can someone advise on where I might be going wrong? How can I ensure fonts are kept of similar sizes on both android and ios, and not have wrapping on my android?

Thanks!

Comment: I am reading all about viewport on w3schools.com and a thought just crossed my mind - how will my output vary if the operator changes from portrait to landscape? Will it redraw? (I let jquerymobile decide on widths but suspect I will need trap and respond to orientation changes). Experience/comments welcome on this...

Answer (score 0):

Remove height and target-densitydpi from the viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
```